# (NextJS) How do I place a route into an object as a key value pair?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I'm trying to map an array of objects (itemsList) inside of a drawer component so that each option in the drawer has a name, icon and an onClick listener with a link to another page.  The name and icon currently appear, but the onClick listener doesn't work.  In vanilla React I would use withRouter to export the component and then pass in a history variable as props to accomplish this, but this isn't possible in NextJS.  What would be another way of setting this up?

The drawer and other styling components are from Material UI.

```
import Router, { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Drawer = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const itemsList = [
{
      text: "Home",
      icon: <InboxIcon />,
      onClick: () => router.push('/')
    },
    {
      text: "About",
      icon: <InboxIcon />
      onClick: () => router.push('/about')
    }
  ];

  return (
    <MUIDrawer>
      <List>
        {itemsList.map((item) => {
          const { text, icon } = item;
          return (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              {icon && <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>}
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          );
        })}
      </List>
    </MUIDrawer>
  );
};

export default Drawer;
```

Comment: based on your code, you never passed the `onClick` event into any element. Ex. `<ListItem onClick={item.onClick} />`

Comment: Ah right, simple mistake.  Fixed, thanks.